# Custom server jitsi meet with sdk on Android doesn't work

Tags: android, sdk, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I have a server mounted and functional, I am making my own app for android, with the sdk that is provided, but I can’t get it to connect to my server, it always links to the official meet.jit server.

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder ()
.setServerURL (new URL ("https: // meet.ownserver.com "))
```

Looking at the android studio console, I see that it does not matter what I put on that line (I have tried to put google.com) and nothing, it always links to the official server … how can I change that to link to my server?

Comment: I think you need to `.setRoom()` on the options before `.launch` is called or it will go to the default `meet.jit.si`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically add your own server URL, in the JitsiMeetConferenceOptions class. You can also set some other features within it such as turning off the mic and camera by default when someone enters a room. The custom URL can be added in the same class where you're setting the room name.

Take a look at this code :

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                .setRoom(text)
                .setServerURL(serverURL)
                .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                .setAudioMuted(true)
                .setVideoMuted(true)
                .build();
JitsiMeetActivity.launch(this, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//reset defaultOptions
//put this in MainActivity.java

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    URL serverURL;
    try {
        serverURL = new URL("https://your-meet.example.org");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid server URL!");
    }

    JitsiMeetConferenceOptions defaultOptions = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
            .setServerURL(serverURL)
            .build();
    JitsiMeet.setDefaultConferenceOptions(defaultOptions);}

//change this in proguard-rules.pro
    #-keep class org.jitsi.meet.** { *; } # comment this line
    -keep class use-your-android-manifest-package-name-here.** { *;}
    -keep class org.jitsi.meet.sdk.** { *; }
```